# AuthorizeAttribute not working with Endpoint Routing in ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-3.1

I migrated my ASP.NET Core application from version 2.2 to 3.1. I have a controller with `[Authorize]` attribute like this:

```
[ApiController]
[Authorize(policy: "MyPolicy")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
public class MyController : Controller
```

And the policy is defined in Startup.cs like this:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("MyPolicy",
        policy =>
        {
            policy.RequireRole("MyRole");
            policy.RequireScope("my-scope");
        }
    );
});
```

Everything worked fine in 2.2, but after migrating to 3.1 and enabling Endpoint Routing, this controller began to refuse requests to any endpoint when `[Authorize]` attribute is present, regardless of policy rules (redirecting to the Login page). When I remove `[Authorize]` and look at `User.Claims`, I can see that it does have the required claims (i.e. scope: my-scope, role: MyRole). This happens only if Endpoint Routing is enabled, in case of using `UseMvc` everything works properly. What's wrong with Authorization in Endpoint Routing mode?

UPD: The `Configure` method looks like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseIdentityServer();
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    });
}
```

Comment: show the `Configure`  method

Comment: For reference here is a related question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65028989/authorizeattribute-with-roles-not-working-when-migrating-from-mvc-to-endpoint-ro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working after explicitly setting Authentication Scheme in the policy definition:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("MyPolicy",
        policy =>
        {
            policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            policy.RequireRole("MyRole");
            policy.RequireScope("my-scope");
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Still a mistery why this wasn't needed with `UseMvc` and is mandatory in Endpoint Routing mode. If someone knows please share.